# Modifying Soap UI request using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

we have a requirement of finding the number of dealers in current country.In the below xml request key-value pair will be varied for every request. Inputs to the soap request will be given in .txt file.Based on the number of inputs in .txt file i need to generate key-value pair xml tags dynamically.

```
  **Format of Input.txt**

   1.key1=Fruit,value1=Carrot,Key2=Vegetable,value2=Carrot
   2.key1=Vegetable,value1=Potato
   3.key1=Fruit,value1=Apple,key2=Fruit,value2=Orange,key3=Fruit,value3=Mango
```

**SoapUI Request**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
           <soapenv:Header/>
           <soapenv:Body>
              <web:GetCitiesByCountry>
                 <web:CountryName>Ind</web:CountryName>
                 <web:queryParameters>
                    <web:key>Fruits</web:key>
                    <web:value>Mango</web:value>
                </web:queryParameters>
                <web:queryParameters>
                    <web:key>Vegetables</web:key>
                    <web:value>Carrot</web:value>
                </web:queryParameters>
              </web:GetCitiesByCountry>
           </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: can you show the input and desired output xmls?

Comment: Inut File:

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <web:GetCitiesByCountry>
      <web:CountryName>hello</web:CountryName>
      </web:GetCitiesByCountry>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: Desired Output:

Desired Output:

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <web:GetCitiesByCountry>
      <web:CountryName>hello</web:CountryName>
      </web:GetCitiesByCountry>
<Parameters>
<Key>key1</Key>
<Value>Value1</Value>
</Parameters>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: Are you using file? Please update them on the question. By the way what are the steps in the test case?

Comment: Hi Rao,
I am trying to modify the existing soap request using groovy. In the soap request xml i need to add 

<Parameters> <Key>key1</Key> <Value>Value1</Value> </Parameters> dynamically while executing groovy script

Answer (score 1):

You say you have the reading of the input records sorted, so I've just put some records in a map for demonstration purposes. Then, if your request payload starts off looking like:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <web:GetCitiesByCountry xmlns:web="webserviceX.NET">
            <web:CountryName>hello</web:CountryName>
        </web:GetCitiesByCountry>

    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

You can loop through your input records and append them to the request:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

// Assuming the input document has been read into a HashMap
def map = ['Fruits': 'Banana',
           'Vegetable': 'Potato'        
          ]

// Get testStep by it's name
def testStep = context.testCase.getTestStepByName('soapRequest')

// Parse the request
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(testStep.getPropertyValue('request'))

// Loop through the map and append the key/value pairs
xml.Body.appendNode {
   map.each {k, v ->
      Parameters {      
        Key(k)
        Value(v)
     }
   }
}

// Check the output
log.info(XmlUtil.serialize( xml ))

// Update the request
testStep.setPropertyValue('request',groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( xml ))
```

Afterwards, your request will look like:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <web:GetCitiesByCountry xmlns:web="webserviceX.NET">
            <web:CountryName>hello</web:CountryName>
        </web:GetCitiesByCountry>
        <Parameters>
            <Key>Fruits</Key>
            <Value>Banana</Value>
        </Parameters>
        <Parameters>
            <Key>Vegetable</Key>
            <Value>Potato</Value>
        </Parameters>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said you need to add

```
 <Parameters> <Key>key1</Key> <Value>Value1</Value> </Parameters>
```

dynamically while executing groovy script

So inside your groovy script in a variable

```
 xmlValue="<Parameters> <Key>key1</Key> <Value>Value1</Value> </Parameters>" 
 testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue(xmlNodes,xmlValue)
```

So now your dynamic xml is in testCase property. So inside your xml where you want to place it

you can place this code

```
  <web:CountryName>${#TestCase#xmlValue}</web:CountryName>
```

This way it will get added. If you pass it null,then nothing will be added in your xml.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is really helpful if i have requirement of only one key value pair. 

Is their any way to add key-value pair xml tags to parameters xml tag without hard coding. Because key-value pair will not always be 1 it can be 2 or 3 etc.

Comment: But it does not sound the above yields the desired output as well as is.

Comment: @lokeshchitturi, can specify the your use case correctly be editing your question instead of comments? On what basis, the number of keys would change?

Comment: i hope modified question will you idea on what i need

Comment: @lokeshchitturi you could write a code to read the file. One line would be read at a time. you can form a logic to generate the key value pair and assign the final value to "xmlValue" and then set Property Value.. So this way at every read of line from the file. we will have different key value pair generated and assigned to property value. you can first use split on(,) to get key1=Fruit and then split on (=)  this way you can generate value

Comment: Yeah i got the logic of that but i am stuck at generating the key-value pair xml tags in Soap UI Request. It would be great if u can help in that. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need not to do that. If you have got the logic to generate  "xmlValue" from my code. You can directly use inside xml ${#TestCase#xmlValue}

Answer (score 0):

There's some good technical solutions here, but if you buy a SoapUI license, you'll be able to access the data driven test functionality, which does exactly what you want right out of the box.  No groovy scripts required.