# How do I build a base64 string from properties in SoapUI?

Tags: soap, groovy, automated-tests, soapui

Here is what I've got.

- There is a SOAP message that sends a base64 encoded clob as the data.
- The clob is an xml file that is built from a set of properties we want to modify.

The questions I think I have are:

- How do I pull properties to generate the xml
- How do I convert that xml to a base64 encoded string
- How do I take that base64 encoded string and add it to my payload?

I appreciate your time :)

Comment: You can automate tests with SoapUI and run them from command line or from within SoapUI, and you can run scripts that can generate payload content that you can then insert into the SOAP message ([for ex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706342/modifying-soap-ui-request-using-groovy)). You will have to do some reading of the [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/docs/). You may also want to consider asking on the SoapUI [community](https://www.soapui.org/resources/), for better chances of getting a response

Comment: Fair response. I'm currently stuck on the first question about reading properties.

if I use
```
def propertyValue = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("url")
```

it returns 'null'

when I use 

```
def propertyValue = "${#TestSuite#url}"
```

I get 'unexpected character '#' found' message.

Comment: Additionally, when I use a built-in property at the test case level....

```
def propertyValue = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("Username")
```

I still get 'null'

Comment: def propertyValue = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("url") ......... works, though not really intuitive... onto the next question (which I hope is simpler :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sample does the trick.

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer) 
def propertyUrl = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("url")

xml.records() { 
    car(name: 'HSV Maloo', make: 'Holden', year: 2006) {
        country('Australia')
        record(type: 'speed', propertyUrl)
    }
    car(name: 'Royale', make: 'Bugatti', year: 1931) {
        country('France')
        record(type: 'price', 'Most Valuable Car at $15 million')
    }
}

def records = new XmlSlurper().parseText(writer.toString()) 

xmlString = writer.toString()
log.info(xmlString)

xmlBase64 = xmlString.bytes.encodeBase64()
log.info(xmlBase64);
```

A couple things stumped me initially

- The specific incantation to get the property from the test
- using 'groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder' instead of just 'MarkupBuilder'

After that, it was a piece of cake :)